# Joomla: fetch data from table to include it into the link

Tags: joomla

Let's imagine we have a web-page with the content and one of the elements is table where we have couple of columns. It is done with `Joomla`, so basically I am working with the web-page constructor if I can call it like this and not with code. In the last column I have a link with query parameters, so something like this: `link?qparam1=sth1&qparam2=sth`. The values for these query parameters should be taken from the first and second column and inserted in this link. Otherwise I need manually to copy those values to each and every link which makes in very slow and inefficient especially when table values are changed, the link must be updated as well.

*Is it possible to fetch the data from columns and include into the link?*

Comment: Is it possible? Yes.  Is your question **Too Broad**? Yes.  Once you have researched and attempted to self-solve then become stuck, please post your Joomla question at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Well, personally I don't think that it is too broad question. Thanks for point out Joomla stack exchange.

Comment: It seems you are asking for a tutorial <-- that's generally a symptom that  a question hasn't been refined down to an isolated issue.

Answer (score 0):

Write a system plugin, Get data from a table, insert/update data to request

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->input->set('qparam1','<value from table>');
```

it will update request data.